# Insert into a specific row of a table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to select the row in a table where the id = user and once I have that row I want to insert into the docId column the value docId. To do this I have tried this:

```
INSERT INTO (SELECT * FROM users WHERE (id='"+user+"')); (docId) VALUES ('"+docId+"')
```

but this does not work

Comment: https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/update.php

Comment: Sounds you are looking for UPDATE instruction not INSERT. Could you please confirm if "docId" is a column of "users" table or not?

Comment: thanks everyone UPDATE was exactly what was needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want:

```
update users 
    set docId = ?
    where id = ?
```

Do not munge the query string with parameter values.  These only cause unexpected syntax errors and make the code vulnerable to SQL injection.  Learn to use parameters.

Answer (score -1):

Try INSERT INTO TableNmae(SELECT * FROM users WHERE (id='value') and (docId) = ('value1'))